# how to solve confusion mac address due to USB Ethernet on system

Tags: ethernet, certificate, mac-address

I am using a packet analysis solution program that licensing certification based on Mac address.

When I insert USB Ethernet card, licensing certification often breaks off.

So.. I think that the licensing certification progress of solution would be confuses whether to select which of two mac address.

how to solve this problem?

Comment: This is something you would need to take up with the vendor.

Answer (score 2):

Talk to the vendor. I'm sure they must have some process to handle people upgrading their network interfaces.